# C 'restrict' keyword based optimisation

Tags: c, restrict

There are following structures:

```
typedef struct test_def {
  int a, b, c;
} test_def_t;

typedef struct test {
  test_def_t const * const def;
} test_t;
```

I want want to use them like this:

```
test_def_t initial_def;
test_t * object;

initial_def.a = 123;
initial_def.b = 456;
initial_def.c = 789;

init_object(&object, &initial_def);
```

Now, `object->def` is a pointer to **a copy** of `initial_def`.

Later, I will use code which often fetches values from `object->def`. I know that this `object->def` is read-only and will never change.

Example:

```
for(int a = 0; a < object->def->a; ++a)
  for(int b = 0; b < object->def->b; ++b)
    for(int c = 0; c < object->def->c; ++c)
      do_something(object);
```

**Question #1**: Does the compiler load `object->def->a` and the rest every iteration, even if it can be loaded once?

**Question #2**: Does using `restrict` like below change this behavior?

```
typedef struct test {
  test_def const * const restrict def;
                      /* ^^^^^^^^ */
} test_t;
```

**Question #3**: Should I also use `test_t * restrict object` instead of just `test_t * object` to increase optimisation when I use the `object` only locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You've told the compiler that `object->def` doesn't change, so it can assume that the information is not changed by the call to `do_something()`, so it could avoid reloading the loop limits on each iteration of each loop.  However, it is not obliged to make such an optimization.  You'd have to look at the generated assembler to know whether it does make the optimization or not.
2. Using `restrict` would have no bearing on this whatsoever.
3. N/A — `restrict` simply indicates that there is no other pointer to the object.